# Esp32 cam sends the image and python receives the color image

Tags: python

I have a code that works only with one detail that the image is seen in grayscale and I need it to be a jpg or color.

i Try from an esp32 camera server to send an image to a python client

Python Code:

```
import websocket # pip install websocket-client
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# Image dimensions - this needs to match our setting on the ESP32 CAM board
IMG_X = 320 # QVGA 320x240
IMG_Y = 240

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://192.168.1.3") # Use the IP address from the ESP32 board - printed to the serial monitor
#192.168.1.3 IP DE ESP32

while(1):
    # Ask the user for some input and transmit it
    str = input("Say something: ")
    if (str == "exit"):
        break
    
    # sent the input string across the socket
    ws.send(str)

    # Wait for server to respond and print it
    if (str == "capture"):
        binResp = ws.recv_frame() # receiving binary image data (we assume grey scale) from camera
  
        # we are going to store the received binary image data in an array... 
        img_array = np.zeros((IMG_Y,IMG_X))
        x = 0
        y = 0
        count = 0

        # traverse the captured data one byte at a time and populate image array
        for byte in bytearray(binResp.data):
           #print (byte)
           y = count // IMG_X
           x = count % IMG_X
           img_array[y,x] = byte
           count = count + 1

        # display captured image
        plt.figure('Capture Image 1')
        plt.imshow(img_array)
        plt.set_cmap('gray')
        plt.show(block=False)

    else:
       result = ws.recv()
       print("Received: " + result)

# Gracefully close WebSocket connection
ws.close()`
```

Esp32 Cam Code:

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>

// Select camera model
#define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT // Has PSRAM
#include "esp_camera.h"

const char* ssid     = "Wifi";     // input your wifi name
const char* password = "password";   // input your wifi passwords


#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27
#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22


// Globals
WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(80);
 
// Called when receiving any WebSocket message
void onWebSocketEvent(uint8_t num,
                      WStype_t type,
                      uint8_t * payload,
                      size_t length) {

  // Figure out the type of WebSocket event
  switch(type) {

    // Client has disconnected
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.printf("[%u] Disconnected!\n", num);
      break;

    // New client has connected
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      {
        IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
        Serial.printf("[%u] Connection from ", num);
        Serial.println(ip.toString());
      }
      break;

    // Echo text message back to client
    case WStype_TEXT:
      Serial.printf("[%u] Text: %s\n", num, payload);
      Serial.println((char*)payload);

      if (String((char*)payload) == "capture")
      {
        Serial.println("Capture Command Received - capturing frame");

        camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
        fb = esp_camera_fb_get(); // get image... part of work-around to get latest image
        esp_camera_fb_return(fb); // return fb... part of work-around to get latest image
        
        fb = NULL;
        fb = esp_camera_fb_get(); // get fresh image
        size_t fbsize = fb->len;
        Serial.println(fbsize);
        Serial.println("Image captured. Returning frame buffer data.");
        webSocket.sendBIN(num, fb->buf, fbsize);
        esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
        Serial.println("Done");
      } else
      {
        webSocket.sendTXT(num, payload);
      }
      break;

    // For everything else: do nothing
    case WStype_BIN:
     // Serial.printf("[%u] get binary length: %u\n", num, length);
     // hexdump(payload, length);

      // send message to client
      // webSocket.sendBIN(num, payload, length);
     // break;
    case WStype_ERROR:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_TEXT_START:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_BIN_START:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_FIN:
    default:
      break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.println("Connecting...");

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_GRAYSCALE;
  
  // if PSRAM IC present, init with UXGA resolution and higher JPEG quality
  //                      for larger pre-allocated frame buffer.
  //if(psramFound()){
  //  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
  //  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  //  config.fb_count = 2;
  //} else {
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_QVGA; //FRAMESIZE_96X96; //FRAMESIZE_QQVGA; //FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 12;
  config.fb_count = 1;
  //}

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Msg: Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  // drop down frame size for higher initial frame rate
  s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_QVGA);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  Serial.print("Msg: Camera Ready! Use 'http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("' to connect");

  // Start WebSocket server and assign callback
  webSocket.begin();
  webSocket.onEvent(onWebSocketEvent);
}

void loop() {
  // Look for and handle WebSocket data
  webSocket.loop();
}
```

I have tried everything I could to use matrices with 3 data because it is three-color RGB, also modifying the esp32 cam code so that it sends the photo to jpg

I also admit that I forgot to comment the code where it says gray in python but it doesn't work either

Add:I think the error is in the python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own question.

Now the color image is received on the Python computer also with better resolution.

Code Esp32 Cam

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>

// Select camera model
#define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT // Has PSRAM
#include "esp_camera.h"

const char* ssid     = "Wifi";     // input your wifi name
const char* password = "password";   // input your wifi passwords

// Definir los pines del módulo ESP32 CAM
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27
#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22


// Globals
WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(80);
 
// Called when receiving any WebSocket message
void onWebSocketEvent(uint8_t num,
                      WStype_t type,
                      uint8_t * payload,
                      size_t length) {

  // Figure out the type of WebSocket event
  switch(type) {

    // Client has disconnected
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.printf("[%u] Disconnected!\n", num);
      break;

    // New client has connected
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      {
        IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
        Serial.printf("[%u] Connection from ", num);
        Serial.println(ip.toString());
      }
      break;

    // Echo text message back to client
    case WStype_TEXT:
      Serial.printf("[%u] Text: %s\n", num, payload);
      Serial.println((char*)payload);

      if (String((char*)payload) == "capture")
      {
        Serial.println("Capture Command Received - capturing frame");

        camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
        fb = esp_camera_fb_get(); // get image... part of work-around to get latest image
        esp_camera_fb_return(fb); // return fb... part of work-around to get latest image
        
        fb = NULL;
        fb = esp_camera_fb_get(); // get fresh image
        size_t fbsize = fb->len;
        Serial.println(fbsize);
        Serial.println("Image captured. Returning frame buffer data.");
        webSocket.sendBIN(num, fb->buf, fbsize);
        esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
        Serial.println("Done");
      } else
      {
        webSocket.sendTXT(num, payload);
      }
      break;

    // For everything else: do nothing
    case WStype_BIN:
     // Serial.printf("[%u] get binary length: %u\n", num, length);
     // hexdump(payload, length);

      // send message to client
      // webSocket.sendBIN(num, payload, length);
     // break;
    case WStype_ERROR:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_TEXT_START:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_BIN_START:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_FIN:
    default:
      break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.println("Connecting...");

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  
  // if PSRAM IC present, init with UXGA resolution and higher JPEG quality
  //                      for larger pre-allocated frame buffer.
  //if(psramFound()){
  //  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
  //  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  //  config.fb_count = 2;
  //} else {
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA; //FRAMESIZE_96X96; //FRAMESIZE_QQVGA; //FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  config.fb_count = 1;
  //}

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Msg: Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  // drop down frame size for higher initial frame rate
  s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_SVGA);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  Serial.print("Msg: Camera Ready! Use 'http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("' to connect");

  // Start WebSocket server and assign callback
  webSocket.begin();
  webSocket.onEvent(onWebSocketEvent);
}

void loop() {
  // Look for and handle WebSocket data
  webSocket.loop();
}
```

Code Python:

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import aiofiles

# The main function that will handle connection and communication
# with the server
async def ws_client():
    print("WebSocket: Client Connected.")
    url = "ws://192.168.1.3:80"
    # Connect to the server
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        name = input("capture or exit: ")

        if name == 'exit':
            exit()

        #age = input("Your Age: ")
        # Send values to the server
        await ws.send(f"{name}")
        #await ws.send(f"{age}")

        # Stay alive forever, listen to incoming msgs
        while True:
            # Receive binary data
            data = await ws.recv()
            # Save the binary data to a file
            async with aiofiles.open('received_image.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
                await out_file.write(data)
            print("Image received and saved.")
            break

# Start the connection
asyncio.run(ws_client())
```

I inserted an image but I can't add it because I don't have enough reputation to add it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRqg9.jpg)